# Currentsection TOC in scrartcl?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, subdividing

I like to get a toc at beginning of some of my sections, like in beamer where I can use `\tableofcontents[currentsection]` is there a possibility in scrartcl?

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents %complete

\section{First}

\section{Second}
\tableofcontents %just subsection and subsubsection
\subsection{SecondSub}
\subsubsection{please}
\subsection{this}
\subsection{SecondSub2}
\subsection{parts}

\section{Third}
\subsection{another}

\end{document}
```

Looks like:

```
Inhaltsverzeichnis %complete

1 First

2 Second
2.1 SecondSub.......................2
2.1.1 please........................2
2.1.2 this..........................2
2.2. SecondSub2.....................3
2.2.1 parts.........................4

3 Third
3.1 another ........................5


1 First

2 Second

Inhaltsverzeichnis %just subsection and subsubsection
2.1 SecondSub.......................2
 2.1.1 please........................2
 2.1.2 this..........................2
2.2. SecondSub2.....................3
 2.2.1 parts.........................4

2.1 SecondSub

2.1.1 please 

2.1.2 this

2.2. SecondSub2

2.2.1 parts


3 Third

3.1 another
```

Comment: Welcome. See package `etoc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using `etoc`. It's just a starting point.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{\contentsname}}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\section{First}

\section{Second}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{SecondSub}
\subsubsection{please}
\subsection{this}
\subsection{SecondSub2}
\subsection{parts}

\section{Third}
\subsection{another}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sorry was busy.
It's what I was looking for and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use KOMA-Script's alpha package `scrwfile` and a local redefinition of some `\l@…` commands and local changes of `tocdepth`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scrwfile}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{sectiontocdepth}
\setcounter{sectiontocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\newcommand*{\sectiontoc}{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\noexpand\setcounter{tocdepth}{\the\value{tocdepth}}}%
  \begingroup
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}%
    \let\l@part\@gobbletwo
    \def\l@section##1##2{%
      \begingroup
        \def\numberline####1{%
          \ifstr{####1}{\thesection}{%
            \setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{sectiontocdepth}}%
          }{%
            \setcounter{tocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}%
          }%
        }%
        \sbox\@tempboxa{##1}%
      \endgroup
    }%
    \listoftoc*{toc}%
  \endgroup
  \reserved@a
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{sectiontocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents %complete

\section{First}

\section{Second}
\sectiontoc
\subsection{SecondSub}
\subsubsection{please}
\subsection{this}
\subsection{SecondSub2}
\subsection{parts}

\section{Third}
\subsection{another}

\end{document}
```

[image: page with table of contents and section table of contents]

Note, that it works only for numbered sections.

If you want a heading above the section ToC, replace

```
\listoftoc*{toc}
```

by

```
\setuptoc{toc}{leveldown}%
\listoftoc{toc}%
```

and you'll get:

[image: section toc with headline]

Alpha package `scrwfile` is used to avoid `\tableofcontents` (and `\listoftoc*` or `listoftoc`) to remove the contents of the `toc` file. See the manual for possible issues.

Answer (score 1):

Question [Table of contents with current section accentuated (not in Beamer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374140/table-of-contents-with-current-section-accentuated-not-in-beamer) was marked as an exact duplicate which I don't think it is. (or rather perhaps the question is, but the existing 
answers are in slightly different spirit, it seems; here the section itself is part of the printed table of contents)

Thus I am providing here an answer to that question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SectionFromToc}[1]{\ifnum#1=\value{section}%
        \color{black}%
        \expandafter\@SectionFromToc\else\color{gray}\fi}

% without hyperref, do not use #4 here.
\def\@SectionFromToc \contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
    \section*{{\def\mysecnumber{\makebox[1.5em][l]}#2}}
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mysecnumber[1]{}

\makeatother

\newcommand\mysection[1]{%
 \clearpage
 \refstepcounter{section}%
 \addtocontents{toc}{\SectionFromToc{\the\value{section}}}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\mysecnumber{\the\value{section}}#1}%
 \tableofcontents
}                    
\etocsettocstyle{}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\mysection{Section 1}

Content of Section 1

\mysection{Section 2}

Content of Section 2

\mysection{Section 3}

Content of Section 3

\mysection{Section 4}

Content of Section 4
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to give a better idea of what this gives as result, here is with rather

```
\etocsettocstyle{}{\vspace{2\baselineskip}}
```

[image]

Here is with some added subsections:

[image]